Question on Abundance Ratios and Maximum Values
I'm currently working through Lemma 5.3 in this paper, which states the following:
$$
\max \left\{ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} \mid n \text{ has factorization pattern } \vec{e} \right\} = \frac{\sigma(m(\vec{e}))}{m(\vec{e})}.
$$
The proof makes use of Lemma 5.2, which states that if $ q > p $ are primes and $ f > e $, then
$$
\frac{\sigma(p^f q^e)}{p^f q^e} > \frac{\sigma(p^e q^f)}{p^e q^f}.
$$
Here are my main questions and points of confusion regarding the proof:

Ordering of Primes: In the beginning, the proof says that we can assume that primes are ordered from smallest to largest. It seems that this ordering is derived from the fact that the abundance index $ \frac{\sigma(p^e)}{p^e} $ is larger for smaller primes, so we prioritize smaller primes for the same exponent. Is this assumption of ordering based solely on this reasoning?

Application of Lemma 5.2 to Deduce Exponent Ordering: The proof then applies Lemma 5.2 to conclude that the exponents $ f_1 \ge f_2 \ge \cdots \ge f_s $ for the primes in the factorization. However, Lemma 5.2 itself assumes $ f > e $ and $ q > p $, which seems to imply a certain ordering of exponents to use this Lemma. My question is: does the proof assume the order $ f_1 \ge f_2 \ge \cdots \ge f_s $ from the beginning, or does it deduce this ordering through repeated applications of Lemma 5.2?


Any clarification on these points would be very helpful. Thank you!

recommend you get your hands dirty. Like continued fractions, there is a fair amount of alphabet soup involved. However, working out the construction from Alaoglu and Erdos is not that bad, and writing a program to find the first few dozen CA numbers  is not bad either. Here is mine, for each one it runs my little homegrown factoring function.
=========================================================

 ( 0.5849625007211564 , 2 , 1 )    2 =  2
 ( 0.2618595071429147 , 3 , 1 )    6 =  2 3
 ( 0.2223924213364479 , 2 , 2 )    12 =  2^2 3
 ( 0.1132827525593782 , 5 , 1 )    60 =  2^2 3 5
 ( 0.09953567355091472 , 2 , 3 )    120 =  2^3 3 5
 ( 0.07285801232987818 , 3 , 2 )    360 =  2^3 3^2 5
 ( 0.06862156132406659 , 7 , 1 )    2520 =  2^3 3^2 5 7
 ( 0.04730571477835724 , 2 , 4 )    5040 =  2^4 3^2 5 7
 ( 0.03628656262710209 , 11 , 1 )    55440 =  2^4 3^2 5 7 11
 ( 0.02889256738661865 , 13 , 1 )    720720 =  2^4 3^2 5 7 11 13
 ( 0.02308361311304093 , 2 , 5 )    1441440 =  2^5 3^2 5 7 11 13
 ( 0.02304526195950645 , 3 , 3 )    4324320 =  2^5 3^3 5 7 11 13
 ( 0.02037346241794454 , 5 , 2 )    21621600 =  2^5 3^3 5^2 7 11 13
 ( 0.0201744121952064 , 17 , 1 )    367567200 =  2^5 3^3 5^2 7 11 13 17
 ( 0.01742039646617879 , 19 , 1 )    6983776800 =  2^5 3^3 5^2 7 11 13 17 19
 ( 0.01357349479472212 , 23 , 1 )    160626866400 =  2^5 3^3 5^2 7 11 13 17 19 23
 ( 0.01140476327224931 , 2 , 6 )    321253732800 =  2^6 3^3 5^2 7 11 13 17 19 23
 ( 0.01006788633590815 , 29 , 1 )    9316358251200 =  2^6 3^3 5^2 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
 ( 0.009245432910499373 , 31 , 1 )    288807105787200 =  2^6 3^3 5^2 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31
 ( 0.009095783332028037 , 7 , 2 )    2021649740510400 =  2^6 3^3 5^2 7^2 11 13 17 19 23 29 31

=========================================================

2, 6, 12, 60, 120, 360, 2520, 5040, 55440, 720720, 1441440, 4324320, 21621600, 367567200, 6983776800, 160626866400, 321253732800, 9316358251200, 288807105787200, 2021649740510400, 

